# ¿Cómo cambiar la carpeta por defecto de Maven (src/main/resource)?

Tags: xml, javafx, maven, fxml

Estoy usando JavaFX, así que los archivos son **fxml**. 
 Mi problema radica en que los archivos **fxml** solo pueden ser reconocidos cuando se encuentran en la carpeta resource, pero yo quiero que puedan ser leídos por otra ruta, en este caso: **"src/main/java/com/example/View"** 
Muestro la estructura de las carpetas:

```
src
   main
      java
         com
            example
               View
                  primary.fxml
                  secondary.fxml 
pom.xml
```

Aquí un fragmento de código del **pom.xml**:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java/com/example/View</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

Es lo que he intentado hacer, pero me sale error: 
[image: InvocationTargetException]

Nota: Ese error solo se muestra si mis archivos **.fxml** se encuentran en la carpeta */View* y especifico su ruta en el **pom.xml** tal como lo mostré en el fragmento de código.

Comment: los archivos que no se compilan van en src/main/res  no en src/main/java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta a esta pregunta, es que se debe crear un archivo **module-info.java**. El **pom.xml** no era necesario. 
Aquí muestro la ubicación del archivo **module-info.java**:

```
src/
├─ main/
│  ├─ java/
│  │  ├─ module-info.java
│  │  └─ com/
│  │     └─ example/
│  │        ├─ Controller/
│  │        │  ├─ PrimaryController.java
│  │        │  └─ SecondaryController.java
│  │        └─ View/
│  │           ├─ primary.fxml
│  │           ├─ secondary.fxml
│  │
```

En el método heredado **(start)** de la clase *Application* se le debe especificar la ruta, no solo el nombre del archivo *(.fxml)*.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    scene = new Scene(loadFXML("View/primary"), 640, 480);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Primary view");
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
public static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
    scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
}

private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
    return fxmlLoader.load();
}
```

Y aquí el código del archivo **module-info.java**:

```
module com.example {
   requires javafx.controls;
   requires javafx.fxml;

   opens com.example.View to javafx.fxml;
   opens com.example.Controller to javafx.fxml;

   exports com.example.View to javafx.fxml;
   exports com.example.Controller to javafx.fxml;

   exports com.example to javafx.graphics;
}
```

Nota: El fragmento de código del **pom.xml** debe ser borrado.